# ASP.NET/IIS: Log out all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, authentication, asp.net-3.5

In an ASP.NET 3.5 application running on IIS, how do I force a "deauthentication" of all currently logged-in and authenticated users?

`iisreset` didn't seem to do the trick!

Comment: Please explain your authentication mechanism and how you store your session information.

Comment: Timores is correct more information is required on your authentication mechanism, simply resetting IIS is unlikely to reset authentication in a number of scenarios

Comment: I'm using the authentication system in a CMS called EPiServer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET authentication is designed to be resilient to an IISReset due to its use of cookies - performing an IISReset will clear any in-memory information, but the next time a user asks for a page on your site, they will send their authentication token, which (if it hasn't timed out) will still be valid, and the server will re-authenticate them.

You could write something that would effectively log out the user after a restart, by (for example) storing the application start time in a global variable in `Application_Start`, and then comparing the users `LastActivityDate` with that value - if it's before the start time, then you can call the appropriate sign-out method during `Application_SessionStart` or `Application_BeginRequest`.

Answer (score 7):

Changing the authentication form name will then require new authentication from all users.

From:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="originalName" loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  />
</authentication>
```

To:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="differentName" loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  />
</authentication>
```